# Find the expression of an angle within an equation that contain sin(angle) and cos(angle)

Tags: trigonometry

Let's consider the following equation:

$$R = \frac{p  D\cos\theta}{p - D \sin\theta}$$

Where $R,p,D>0$ and $-\pi/2\le\theta\le0$.

The goal is to transform this formula in order to write something like $\theta = f(R,p,D)$

My first try was to write the equation like below:

$$Rp = D(p\cos\theta + R\sin\theta)$$

Then considering the case where $p=R$, I was able to do this:

\begin{align}
 R & = D(\cos\theta + \sin\theta) \\
 & = D\sqrt{2}[\sin(\pi/4)\cos\theta + \cos(\pi/4)\sin\theta] \\
 & = D\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4 + \theta) \\
 \theta& = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{R}{D\sqrt{2}}\right) - \frac{\pi}{4} \\
\end{align}

I can do the same considering the angles $\pi/3$ and $\pi/6$ but in all the cases I had to fix the relation between $p$ and $R$ which is not what I want.

---

I also tried to use the following equation:

$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ ,  $\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ where $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$

I ended with a second degree equation

$$(\frac{R}{D} - 1)t^2 - 2\frac{R}{p}t + (\frac{R}{D} - 1) = 0$$

I calculated the solution  but I obtained wrong values when testing with the initial formula. probably I missing something on the road.

Is there a *magic* step or an equation that can help me find $\theta = f(R,p,D)$?

---

For the reference, this question is a extension of [my answer in StakOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57432702/8620333) and below is the figure from where the initial equation was extracted. Probably I didn't extract the good equation and there is a better one that suits my needs.

[image]

Comment: Feel free to add any relevant tag to the question. Not sure what are the ones that may apply here in addition to *trigonometry*

Comment: Looks you're trying to express $a\cos\theta + b\sin\theta$ as a single sinusoid ?

Comment: @ganeshie8 yes, kind of. I was able to do it for particular values of $a$ and $b$ but didn't find a generic formula

Comment: There is a nice formula. Look at this short video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3Ky61hBEjE

Comment: You should get
$$p\cos\theta + R\sin\theta = \sqrt{p^2+R^2} \cos(\theta - \tan^{-1}(R/p))$$

Comment: @ganeshie8 great thanks! looks like this is what I am missing, didn't find such formula. I was pretty sure that the particular cases I found was hiding a generic formula

Comment: yw:) that formula shows up in engineering a lot... worth memorizing if you're going to work on laplace transforms, differential equations etc..

Comment: @TemaniAfif You can use the [Sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine_and_cosine) formula in Wikipedia's "List of trigonometric identities" article to combine $p\cos\theta + R\sin\theta$ into one $\sin$ term.

Comment: @JohnOmielan looks like I didn't scroll enough on this page ...

Comment: @ganeshie8 well, my engineering days are behind me (I miss them). Now I am using some *light* maths in the HTML/CSS world to find accurate result when dealing with complex transformation and shapes so I don't think I will meet laplace or differential equation ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif just noticed you're a god in stackoverflow! your work sounds very interesting.. I agree when you can come here for quick math help, there is no point in memorizing stuff haha :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From here:
$$
Rp = D(p\cos\theta + R\sin\theta)
$$
divide through by $D\sqrt{p^2+R^2}$ to get
$$
\frac{Rp}{D\sqrt{p^2+R^2}} = \frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+R^2}}\cos\theta + \frac{R}{\sqrt{p^2+R^2}}\sin\theta = \sin\left(\theta+\tan^{-1}\frac{p}{R}\right).
$$
Solving for $\theta$ gives
$$
\theta = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{Rp}{D\sqrt{p^2+R^2}}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{p}{R}\right),
$$
which agrees with what you found in the $p = R$ case and will always be negative if $R < D$, as it is in your diagram.

---

There's actually a way to get this same answer from simple trigonometry. The law of sines says that the angle $\phi$ between the red and brown lines satisfies
$$
\frac{\sin\phi}{p} = \frac{\sin O}{D}\;\; \Longrightarrow\;\;\phi = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{pR}{\sqrt{p^2+R^2}}\right)
$$
Meanwhile, the angle $\psi$ between the brown and black lines is just $\tan^{-1}(p/R)$. Since the exterior angle of a triangle is the sum of the other two interior angles (and we're treating $\theta$ as negative), we have $-\theta + \phi = \psi$, or
$$
\theta = \phi -\psi = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{pR}{\sqrt{p^2+R^2}}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{p}{R}\right)
$$

Comment: thanks for the answer, will try it shortly. Looks like the key was to consider the fact that I have a $90deg$ angle between R and P which allow me to easily find the hypotenuse using Pythagore